# When was bicycle ridership highest in North America?

Tags: united-states, north-america, modern

Bike commuting share in the United States is currently less than 1%; but in some cities (college towns, really) it is 10% or higher ([source](https://bikeleague.org/sites/default/files/Where_We_Ride_2017_KM_0.pdf)).

Is there a time in US history when bicycle ridership was more prevalent than now? What is the evidence to demonstrate that bicycle ridership was high?

Comment: Are you asking about just bike commuting, or all bicycle riding?  Because there are a lot of people who ride for exercise and/or recreation, but not for commuting.  For instance, mountain biking &c.  (FWIW, I ride fairly regularly, but haven't commuted to work by any means for over a decade, thanks to telecommuting.)

Comment: Try the late 19th/early 20th century. See https://history.stackexchange.com/a/54030/11883

Comment: it is well established fact that the Bicycle Clubs of the period 1880 to 1910 successfully lobbied to get roads, both municipal and inter-city, paved for the convenience of commuting and touring cyclists. These clubs were big, and patronized by the wealthiest citizens, in both North America and Western Europe.

Comment: @jamesqf I'm looking for hard evidence that there was a time in US history when people (as a percentage of the total population) rode bikes than they do now. Commuter data is incomplete, but readily accessible, at least for the present. Perhaps bicycle sales numbers would paint a clear picture?

Comment: As noted in [my linked answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/54027/how-would-a-family-travel-from-indiana-to-texas-in-1911/54029?noredirect=1#comment159309_54029): "*The number of bicycles in production skyrocketed to over a million per year by 1899*" That's between a quarter and a third of [U.S. domestic automobile production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U.S._Automobile_Production_Figures) in the 21st Century, for a mucyh larger population.

Comment: Answer me this: Precisely where do you think the Dunlop Tire Company got the funds to buy and donate a [6 foot high silver trophy for the Ontario Dunlop Trophy Race](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsvyw.jpg), in 1894 [when registered motor vehicles in the U.S.](https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/ohim/summary95/mv200.pdf) numbered less than 10,000, if not from selling pneumatic bicycle tires in the hundreds of thousands or even millions?

Comment: @kingledion: I don't think bicycle sales numbers would really give you a good handle, though, since many people keep bikes for decades.

Comment: @Pieter Geerkens: I would imagine Dunlop tire also made pneumatic tires for horse-drawn wagons & carriages.  As far as prizes go, the Tour de France had  €2,291,700 in prize money in 2019 (per Google), while bicycle makers & others provide multi-million dollar salaries to top professional team members.  And that's something most ordinary bikers like me simply don't care about.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - In absence of other better objective numbers, I think an answer based around production numbers would be quite serviceable.

Comment: After Colorado legalized marijuana, the probably highest bicycle ridership in North America became definitely the highest.  Oops, you meant numerically, not altitude and attitude....

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a time in US history when bicycle ridership was more prevalent than now?

I haven't tried very hard to dig up hard data, but based on general trends, I suspect **probably not**. [The Wikipedia article on "bike booms"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bike_boom) is illuminating here. The 1890s was the first major wave of popularity for bicylcing, but at that it was almost exclusively done for amusement. After that it mostly became a children's activity up to the 1970s. The high popularity of bicycles for adult both for sport and for practical purposes is fairly recent.